# Norm of a linear function on $c_{0}$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $c_0$ be the space of all sequences which converge to $0$. Let $f: c_0 \to\mathbb{R}$ by $$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x_n}{n^2}$$ What is the value of $\|f\|$?.

I am just getting used to the definitions. So a formal solution would be very helpful.

I know that $\displaystyle \|f(x)\| = \sup_{x \in S_X} |f(x)|$ where $S_X = \left\{ x \in c_0 \mid \|x\|_\infty \leq 1 \right\}$

Comment: So, you know that every $x_n$ is at most $1$ in absolute value. Can you estimate the sum from above using this information?

Comment: @Thursday So I think $| \sum \frac{x_{n}}{n^2}| \leq \frac{1}{n^2} = \pi^{2}/6$.

Comment: Yes, that's an upper bound. To show it's the supremum, we need some vectors that come close to it. Try a bunch of ones followed by zeros. (Can't use all ones because of the $c_0$ definition.)